# How to prevent Hue in CDH from clearing job history on restart?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, cloudera-cdh, hue, cloudera-manager

I have installed `CDH 5.5.1` with `Hue`, `Hadoop`, `Spark`, `Hive`, `Oozie`, `Yarn` and `ZooKeeper`.

When I run a `Spark` job or `MapReduce` job, `Hue` displays a issue in the job history. The problem is that when I restart the `CDH` services (Not the physical nodes), it removes all the job histories that were before the restart.

[image: Job Browser screenshot]

On Hadoop there are several files that I suspect have information about the task and might be the ones that hold the job information. Their hadoop paths are:

- `/tmp/logs/user/logs/`
- `/user/history/done/2016/`

I have looked for it in the `Cloudera Manager` configuration page, Hue configuration page and some configuration files with no success. I don't know how to prevent this removal. Am I missing something?

Comment: refer this http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2010/11/hadoop-log-location-and-retention/

Comment: The clean way to support it is in progress here https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-3079

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really just need to see job history on a Hadoop cluster, the YARN History Server should have a history of all YARN jobs run on the cluster.

Hue has a JIRA ticket for the issue you describe, titled "Job browser should talk to the YARN history server to display old jobs": https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-2558. Basically, Hue needs to talk to the YARN History Server (not just the Resource Manager) to get the information you're looking for.

The good news is that the task appears to have been completed and included with the release of Hue 4.0, which occurred on 5/11/2017. The bad news is that Cloudera has not yet done a release with that version of Hue rolled in.